# while structuring the data how can I add array of objects with value if the condition matches

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures

I have an object where I am trying to structure it by the key names, as I have a Production subject but it has also a 2nd part, each subject has MCQ, CQ, and total which I want in an array of objects but sometimes in the array of object, there will not be MCQ like the English subject.

I am stuck on adding the subject parts with value in the array of objects.

```js
const result = {
  id: 427,
  merit: "1",
  name: "Israt Jahan",
  group_name: "business",
  GPA: "4.4",
  english_1st_CQ: "24",
  english_1st_total: "24",
  english_2nd_CQ: "24",
  english_2nd_total: "24",
  english_GP: "2",
  english_percentage: "48",
  english_total: "48",
  production_1st_CQ: "32",
  production_1st_MCQ: "11",
  production_1st_total: "43",
  production_2nd_CQ: "26",
  production_2nd_MCQ: "11",
  production_2nd_total: "37",
  production_GP: "5",
  production_percentage: "80",
  roll: 1401,
  total_failed: "0",
  total_gp: "24",
  total_marks: "439",
};

  const subjectAdd = (arr, title) => {
    const node = arr.find((node) => node.subject === title) ?? {
      subject: title.split(" ")[0],
      part_1: [],
      part_2: [],
    };
    if (arr.every((e) => e.subject !== node.subject)) arr.push(node);
    return node;
  };

  const subjects = (data) => {
    const subject = [];
    Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
      const [subjectName, subjectPosition, suffix] = key.split("_");
      if (
        subjectName != "id" &&
        subjectName != "date" &&
        subjectName != "group" &&
        subjectName != "roll" &&
        subjectName != "name" &&
        subjectName != "merit" &&
        subjectName != "GPA" &&
        subjectName != "total"
      ) {
        const newSubject = subjectAdd(subject, `${subjectName}  ${subjectPosition}`);
        const part1 = subjectAdd(newSubject.part_1, `${subjectName}  ${subjectPosition}`);
        const part2 = subjectAdd(newSubject.part_2, `${subjectName}  ${subjectPosition}`);
      }
    });

    return subject;
  };
  console.log("result", subjects(result));
```

Expected output:

```
    [
      {
        subject: "english",
        part_1: [
          {
            subject: "english 1st",
            CQ: 48,
            total: 48,
          },
        ],
        part_2: [
          {
            subject: "english 2nd",
            CQ: 48,
            total: 48,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        subject: "production",
        part_1: [
          {
            subject: "production 1st",
            MCQ:12,
            CQ: 48,
            total: 48,
          },
        ],
        part_2: [
          {
            subject: "production 2nd",
            MCQ:15,
            CQ: 48,
            total: 48,
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach checks for 'english' or 'production' and uses that to decide how to handle the data. If more subjects are added, an array could be used.

I left all the code in a single function for simplicity.

```js
const result = {
  id: 427,
  merit: "1",
  name: "Israt Jahan",
  group_name: "business",
  GPA: "4.4",
  english_1st_CQ: "24",
  english_1st_total: "24",
  english_2nd_CQ: "24",
  english_2nd_total: "24",
  english_GP: "2",
  english_percentage: "48",
  english_total: "48",
  production_1st_CQ: "32",
  production_1st_MCQ: "11",
  production_1st_total: "43",
  production_2nd_CQ: "26",
  production_2nd_MCQ: "11",
  production_2nd_total: "37",
  production_GP: "5",
  production_percentage: "80",
  roll: 1401,
  total_failed: "0",
  total_gp: "24",
  total_marks: "439",
};

const subjects = (data) => {
  const subject = [];
  Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
    const [subjectName, subjectPosition, suffix] = key.split("_");
    if (
      subjectName === "english" || subjectName === "production"
    ) {
      let subj = subject.find(element => element.subject === subjectName);
      if (subj === undefined) {
        // initialize the subject
        subject.push(subj = {
          subject: subjectName
        });
      }
      // check if the first character is a digit
      if (/^\d/.test(subjectPosition)) {
        let pos = "part_" + subjectPosition[0];
        if (typeof subj[pos] === "undefined") {
          // initializae the position
          subj[pos] = { subject: subjectName + " " + subjectPosition };
        }
        subj[pos][suffix] = value;
      }
    }
  });

  return subject;
};
console.log("result", subjects(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to not overcomplicate trying to make everything work with a single function `subjectAdd`, but rather having two separate functions - `subjectAdd` and `partAdd`, for example:

```js
const result = {
  id: 427,
  merit: "1",
  name: "Israt Jahan",
  group_name: "business",
  GPA: "4.4",
  english_1st_CQ: "24",
  english_1st_total: "24",
  english_2nd_CQ: "24",
  english_2nd_total: "24",
  english_GP: "2",
  english_percentage: "48",
  english_total: "48",
  production_1st_CQ: "32",
  production_1st_MCQ: "11",
  production_1st_total: "43",
  production_2nd_CQ: "26",
  production_2nd_MCQ: "11",
  production_2nd_total: "37",
  production_GP: "5",
  production_percentage: "80",
  roll: 1401,
  total_failed: "0",
  total_gp: "24",
  total_marks: "439",
};

  const subjectAdd = (arr, title) => {
    const node = arr.find((node) => node.subject === title) ?? {
      subject: title,
      part_1: [],
      part_2: [],
    };
    if (arr.every((e) => e.subject !== node.subject)) arr.push(node);
    return node;
  };
  const partAdd = (arr, title, key, value) => {
    const node = arr.find((node) => node.subject === title) ?? {
      subject: title,
    };
    node[key] = value;
    if (arr.every((e) => e.subject !== node.subject)) arr.push(node);
    return node;
  };

  const subjects = (data) => {
    const subject = [];
    Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
      const [subjectName, subjectPosition, suffix] = key.split("_");
      if (
        subjectName != "id" &&
        subjectName != "date" &&
        subjectName != "group" &&
        subjectName != "roll" &&
        subjectName != "name" &&
        subjectName != "merit" &&
        subjectName != "GPA" &&
        subjectName != "total"
      ) {
        const newSubject = subjectAdd(subject, `${subjectName}`);
        if (subjectPosition === '1st') {
          partAdd(newSubject.part_1, `${subjectName}  ${subjectPosition}`, suffix, value);
        } else if (subjectPosition === '2nd') {
          partAdd(newSubject.part_2, `${subjectName}  ${subjectPosition}`, suffix, value);
        }
      }
    });

    return subject;
  };
  console.log("result", subjects(result));
```